# Javascript multiple values in variable

Tags: javascript

Is there any way to have one variable with multiple values like this:

```
var variable = 1, 2, 3;
var enteredVal = 1;

if (enteredVal == variable){
    alert('You chose the right number');
}
```

So if the variable enteredVal is equal to 1, 2 or 3, it will alert the message.
I can't seem to get my head around it.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no way to assign multiple distinct values to a single variable.

An alternative is to have `variable` be an [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array), and you can check to see if `enteredval` is in the array.

```
var variable = [1, 2, 3];
var enteredval = 1;

if (variable.indexOf(enteredval) > -1){
    alert('you chose the right number');
}
```

Note that [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) on an array is [not usable in IE8 and below](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff679977%28v=vs.94%29.aspx) (see the Requirements section at the bottom). In that case you would need to use a framework/library's method, or write it yourself:

```
var variable = [1, 2, 3];
var enteredval = 1;

for (var i = 0; i < variable.length; i++) {
    if (variable[i] === enteredval) {
        alert('you chose the right number');
        break; // No need to check all the other values in variable
    }
}
```

To modify arrays after you have instantiated them, take a look at [`push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push), [`pop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop), [`shift`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift), and [`unshift`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift) for adding/removing values. For modifying existing values, you can directly access the index and reassign the value.

```
variable[1] = 5;
// variable is now [1, 5, 3] since arrays are 0-indexed
```

Answer (score 1):

You can store them in an array and use [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) (as long as you don't need IE 8 support):

```
var supportedOptions = [1, 2, 3],
    enteredVal = 1;

if(supportedOptions.indexOf(enteredVal) !== -1) alert("Yep!");
```

Comment: Thanks for answering so fast, i really appreciate it. But i have one more question, how do i add a value to the supportedOptions variable. Like if i later on, by a buttonclick would want to add 4 into the options so it'll be supportedOptions = [1, 2, 3, 4]?

Comment: @user1826795: I really recommend to read a JavaScript tutorial, for example http://eloquentjavascript.net/chapter4.html, and/or have a look at a JavaScript reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array.

Answer (score 1):

Try using an array:

```
var variables = [1, 2, 3];
```

You can access members of the array with `variables[i]`, where `i` is the index of the array, starting at `0`.

`variables[0]` returns `1`

`variables[1]` returns `2`

`variables[2]` returns `3`

This way you can use a `for` loop to iterate through the array:

```
var enteredval = 1; //your guess
for(var i = 0; i < variables.length; i++) { //go through each element
    if(variables[i] == enteredval) { //if they match...
        alert("You chose the right number!"); //...then you got it!
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can store values of the variable as keys in an object. eg:

```
let variable={
  1:0,
  2:0,
  3:0
}

enteredVal=3

if (enteredVal in variable) {
  alert('You chose the right number');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are going to want to create an `array` which can hold multiple values. You would then want to use `index of` to determine if the value is found in the array.

```
var myArray = new Array();

myArray[0] = 1;
myArray[1] = 2;
myArray[2] = 3;
```

Check the value:

```
if(myArray.indexOf(1) > -1){
// exists
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the indexof function of a string.

```
var variable = '1,2,3';
    var enteredval = '1';

    if (variable.indexOf(enteredval) > -1) { alert('you choosed the right number'); };
```