# (a== 1 && a ==2 && a==3) ever evaluate to true in pl sql?

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

Just like some questions here, (a== 1 && a ==2 && a==3) had been proven that it can be evaluated to true in javascript and I'm just wondering if there is also a way in PL/SQL to evaluate it also to true.

Comment: If `a` is a number column, then no, your expression can never evaluate to true.  And if `a` is not numeric, I don't think the query would even run.  Maybe on MySQL it could be true.

Comment: how can a variable have 3 different values at the same time ?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen ahh. thanks bro. I thought it can by some way.

Comment: @NiamatullahBakhshi there are things that you can do outside the box.

Comment: You need to check [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15817932/javascript-multiple-values-in-variable).
There is no way outside the box as far as variables with distinct  values is concerned.

Comment: you need to check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48270127/can-a-1-a-2-a-3-ever-evaluate-to-true/48270314#48270314) too.

Comment: IMHO those answers (craftily) use ambiguous human language and data types to arrive at an answer. In a purely logical sense that expression can never be true, but as you did not specify the data type of `a`, we already have an answer below that makes that expression true.

Comment: Also... PL/SQL doesn't use `==`, it uses `=` so I guess we can be certain  it will only ever evaluate to a syntax error.

Comment: did I say that i'll use == in PL/SQL? @Nick.McDermaid

Comment: That's the code sample that you posted. It's pretty important that you post correct code samples.

Comment: reread my post.

Comment: I think this could be evaluated as true in many languages. "a" doesn't need to specifically be a variable. It can be any expression, and functions could return something to make this true, as Connor shows.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just for fun of course

```
SQL> create or replace
  2  package pkg is
  3    x int := 0;
  4  end;
  5  /

Package created.

SQL>
SQL> create or replace
  2  function a return number is
  3  begin
  4    pkg.x := pkg.x + 1;
  5    return pkg.x;
  6  end;
  7  /

Function created.

SQL>
SQL>
SQL> set serverout on
SQL> begin
  2   if a = 1 and a = 2 and a = 3 then
  3     dbms_output.put_line('BINGO!');
  4   end if;
  5  end;
  6  /
BINGO!

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Comment: I just upvoted the downvote. Great answer that illustrates that even if humans are ambiguous, databases are not!!